# Accessing the QPushButton in the callback function

Tags: c++, qt, callback, qt4, qpushbutton

I want to enable a pushbutton in a callback function. I have tried to do the following but I have got:

```
Runtime received SIGSEGV (address: 0x28 reason: address not mapped to object)
```

```
class MyWindow: public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public: 
   QPushButton *Btn;
   void Scan();
....
};
extern void StartScan(pfcallback);
void MyWindow::Scan()
{
 Btn->setEnabled(false);
 StartScan(Scanfinished);
}
void static Scanfinished()
{
  Btn->setEnabled(true);
}
```

How to access the button in the callback function `Scanfinished()` ?

Comment: Did you forget `Btn = new QPushButton;`?

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile... you're trying to access a member of your class through a global function without defining an instance. You have to learn how to use signals and slots.

Comment: The same case when I do not use static. I have also used the following connect(this, SIGNAL(EnableBtn()), Btn, SLOT(setEnabled(true))); but  I have got the same

Comment: Before posting code on Stackoverflow, you should get your code to compile. Your code is invalid. And one piece of advice: Learn how to use signals and slots in Qt. Don't waste your time with callback functions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you. Your question is tooooooo broad. You don't understand C++ and Qt together. Please read a Qt tutorial. Good luck!

Comment: I have only posted part of the code. The code is too big. I am only asking about the concept. Is it possible to access a widget in a callback function, how?

Comment: "I have only posted part of the code." You were so close to posting an actual example that compiles and works. Why didn't you do that? It'd literally be a couple more lines!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're attempting to manually manage memory. As you can see, it's very easy to use a dangling pointer or commit other blunders. Instead, let the compiler do it for you.
2. You use `static` incorrectly.

If I were to do it, I'd do as follows. The destructor is generated by the compiler and will correctly release all resources and reset `m_instance` to a null value.

```
class MyWindow : public QDialog
{
   Q_OBJECT
   static QPointer<MyWindow> m_instance;
   QVBoxLayout m_layout{this};
   QPushButton m_button{"Scan"};
public:
   MyWindow(QWidget * parent = nullptr) : QDialog(parent) {
      Q_ASSERT(! m_instance);
      m_instance = this;
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_button);
   }
   void Scan();
   static void ScanFinished();
};

QPointer<MyWindow> MyWindow::m_instance;

void StartScan(void(*callback)());

void MyWindow::Scan()
{
   m_button.setEnabled(false);
   StartScan(ScanFinished);
}

void MyWindow::ScanFinished()
{
   m_instance->m_button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

At this point it's rather obvious that the API of `StartScan` is horribly broken, and this brokenness forces the use of a singleton `MyWindow`. When doing any kind of callbacks, you **never** use a sole C function pointer. You **must** accept both a function pointer that takes a `void*` and a `void*` that will be used to carry the data the function needs to work. This **is an idiom**. If you use C-style callbacks, you cannot not use the idiom without severely crippling the usability of your API.

Thus, this is a complete example and works in both Qt 4 and Qt 5. You should have posted something like it - a self-contained test case - in your question. It compiles and it works and you can even get the complete Qt Creator project from github. It will compile and run on all platforms supported by current Qt. It's not supposed to be hard: that's why you're using Qt, after all. Getting in the habit of creating such concise test cases to demonstrate your issues will make you a better developer, and make your questions much easier to answer.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/simple-callback-43094825
#include <QtGui>
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#endif

class MyWindow: public QDialog
{
   Q_OBJECT
   QVBoxLayout m_layout{this};
   QPushButton m_button{"Scan"};
   Q_SIGNAL void ScanFinished();
public:
   MyWindow(QWidget * parent = nullptr) : QDialog(parent) {
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_button);
      connect(&m_button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(Scan()));
      connect(this, SIGNAL(ScanFinished()), this, SLOT(OnScanFinished()));
   }
   Q_SLOT void Scan();
   static void ScanFinishedCallback(void* w);
   Q_SLOT void OnScanFinished();
};

void StartScan(void(*callback)(void*), void* data) {
   // Mockup of the scanning process: invoke the callback after a delay from
   // a worker thread.
   QtConcurrent::run([=]{
      struct Helper : QThread { using QThread::sleep; };
      Helper::sleep(2);
      callback(data);
   });
}

void MyWindow::Scan()
{
   m_button.setEnabled(false);
   StartScan(ScanFinishedCallback, static_cast<void*>(this));
}

void MyWindow::ScanFinishedCallback(void* data)
{
   emit static_cast<MyWindow*>(data)->ScanFinished();
}

void MyWindow::OnScanFinished()
{
   m_button.setEnabled(true);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   MyWindow w;
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Of course `StartScan` cannot do the work in the thread it was called from: it'd block the GUI thread and make your application unresponsive. That's the prime source of bad user experience. Instead, it should spawn a concurrent job that will notify the caller when the scanning is done.

Since the callback will be called from that concurrent thread, it's not safe to use `MyWindow`'s non-thread-safe methods. The only thread-safe methods are signals - thus we can emit a signal that Qt will the safely forward to `MyWindow`'s thread and invoke `OnScanFinished` from the right thread.

Comment: The only that I can emit the signal if I write the following in the ScanFinishedCallback():  MyWindow* Dlg=new MyWindow;
  emit Dlg->ScanFinished();, but unfortunately I have got: QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread

Comment: Fix the broken `StartScan` code to take the necessary `void*` argument **or** use the static `m_instance` pointer to have the instance available in the callback as shown in the 1st part of the answer. You **cannot** create the window in the callback: it won't be connected anywhere, remember that connections are per object, not per class. *The only that I can emit the signal* That's only because you refuse to understand the answer and to fix your code to let you emit the signal correctly. If anything is unclear, ask. You have working, compileable code here to start with.